# How to stop text moving in button upon clicking in C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#

So I'm making a basic calculator in a windows form and am quite new to C#. I have buttons for +, -, / and * and for some reason when I run the program if I click on the '-' button the '-' symbol moves to the bottom of the button. This happens every time I run the program and have tried setting margins and padding to 0 and anchoring but haven't been able to resolve it.  This doesn't happen to the other 3 buttons and the code for them are all the same except for the symbol and button number. I dragged the controls from the toolbox so didn't write any of the code which is why I'm so confused.

The code for the button is as follows:

```
        this.button2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24F);
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(209, 174);
        this.button2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button2.Text = "−";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
```

The margin line of code is the only differing line from the other 3 buttons but the issue persists with or without that line it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you look at the property's of the button if this is windows form's i would assume you draged them into the screen and not hard coded it?

Comment: Can we see your `button2_Click` event?

Comment: Using your code here, I am unable to replicate this issue. Are there any otehr events that interact with button 2?

Comment: Nothing you posted would move anything.  Delete the button and try it again.

Comment: Marc - I have said that in my post yes, finding similar problems on here the suggestions are to set margins and padding to 0 which I have done. What properties would you suggest I look at?

Comment: Jay - Yes looking at it I did add an extra line to change the font and size of the symbol as it was so much smaller than the other ones, I can see why this happens now, thanks!